# How to click on button Apply Now

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

HTML:

```
<a href="https://stgtest.flexforceondemand.com/associateregistration/consenttoproceed?bid=U20xNFozbFBkV0pFZWpWWlpGRjRVMUZJZUVwWFFUMDlPanBnTHhJRmY4R1VRWVh6aFVHN2swcW0%2A&amp;zc=VkdSdVVGZHRTbEZVY3pkWFRYZGFkRTVTUVhFclp6MDlPanJFTUVSazZNV0ErYTdlZ0ovR1BhWng%2A" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Apply Now</a>
```

I have already tried the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Apply Now']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//[@href='Apply Now'])")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='Apply Now']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Apply Now")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("Apply Now")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'btn btn-success btn-lg')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'btn btn-success btn-lg')]")).click();v
```

Comment: please read [mcve] and edit your quesetion.

Answer (score 1):

Try to click with webdriver wait till element is properly loaded in `Dom` and ready to receive `click`.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[.='Apply Now']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1
Try By.CssSelector 
Option 2
Not sure if you are checking if element is exists before clicking on it.if not then use wait.until.
If possible  paste error you are getting here.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to locate and `click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `linkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Apply Now"))).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.btn.btn-success.btn-lg[href*='associateregistration']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-success btn-lg' and contains(@href, 'associateregistration')][text()='Apply Now']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please, maybe it will help

```
driver.findElement(By.id("select2-section-tn-container")).click();
```